# How to use the millisecond in strptime(3)

Tags: c, strptime

I'd like to format the 2023/10/04T11:41:03.553Z with strptime(3) `%Y/%m/%dT%H:%M:%S.???Z`.

What is the input field descriptor of fraction of seconds ?

Although I read through [the document of strptime(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime), I couldn't find any input field descriptor which corresponds to "millisecond".

Comment: What do you expects `strptime` to do with the milliseconds? [struct tm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm) doesn't have a field for milliseconds. The C date/time functions are builtin around epoch time, which is the number of (whole) seconds since midnight Jan 1st, 1970 UTC. You'll need to handle those up front.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround way is to design your own `struct tm` which contains a member for milliseconds:

```c
struct tm2 {
  struct tm tm;
  long ms;
};
```

Then you have to parse the milliseconds part manually （I haved updated the code according to @Fe2O3's comment):

```c
  const char *date = "2023/10/04T11:41:03.553Z";
  struct tm2 tm2;

  char *peroid = strptime(date, "%Y/%m/%dT%H:%M:%S", &tm2.tm);
  if (peroid == NULL) {
    printf("error format!\n");
  } else if (*peroid == '.') {
    char *endstr;
    tm2.ms = strtol(peroid + 1, &endstr, 10);
    if (*endstr != 'Z') {
      printf("error format!\n");
    }
  } else {
    printf("error format!\n");
  }
```

To make the code more robust, you can adjust error checking code.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Good suggestion. I have updated the code.

Comment: Note As `strptime(date, "%Y/%m/%dT%H:%M:%S", &tm2.tm);` does not certainly setting all members of `struct tm`, better to initialize `tm2`: `struct tm2 tm2 = { 0 };` should `tm2` get used later.

Comment: Glad for the update. Robust??? From the man page: "_If strptime() fails to match all of the format string and therefore an error occurred, the function returns NULL._" Not difficult to detect a real problem parsing and avoid dereferencing the NULL pointer... See #2 in this list: http://www.literateprogramming.com/ten-commandments.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Function `strptime()` in not part of any [Standard C library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library).  It is well defined in `*nix` systems.  It commonly uses a pointer to `struct tm`.

`struct tm` is defined to have *at least* 9 members.  It may have more.  There is no *specified* member corresponding to time units finer than *seconds*.

Sometimes `struct tm` has a member for *milliseconds*, *microseconds*, etc.  Yet that is implementation dependent.

Referenced [`strptime()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) simply does not have a specifier for sub-seconds.  Code needs to handle such optional members in some other fashion.

---

**`struct tm` woes**

Without `"%Z"`, `strptime()` forms the `struct tm` without adjusting `.tm_isdst`.  In general,  `strptime()` does not certainly assign all `struct tm` members.

Initialize `struct tm` prior to the `strptime()`.

```
struct tm time_stamp = { 0 };
```

Sample validation:

```
// Return error flag
bool testit(struct tm *t, int *ms, const char *date) {
  memset(t, 0, sizeof *t);

  const char *s = strptime(date, "%Y/%m/%dT%H:%M:%S", &t);
  if (s == NULL) {
    return true;
  }

  int n = 0;
  sscanf(s, ".%3dZ%n", ms, &n);
  return (n < 5 || s[5] != 0);
}
```

---

For the pedantic: detect rump milliseconds as exactly as 3 digits.

```
unsigned char *uc = (unsigned char *)s; 
if (uc[0] != '.' || !isdigit(uc[1]) || !isdigit(uc[2])
    || !isdigit(uc[3]) || uc[4] != 'Z' || uc[5]) {
  return true;
}
uc[4] = 0;
*ms = atoi(s + 1);
return false;
```

Comment: strptime is defined in both the POSIX-2001 and SUSv2 standards, and probably earlier ones.  Hardly "nonstandard".

Comment: @ChrisDodd even with "strptime is defined in both the POSIX-2001 and SUSv2 standards", `strptime()` remains "a non-_standard C library function_".  Standard C spec have never defined it.  As mentioned already: "It is well defined in *nix systems.".

Comment: There are many, *many* standards other than the C spec.  As long as one is clear about which standards one is relying on (including which version of the C spec!) one can write standard compliant code.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Link added.  Note that the [C] tag implies "This tag should be used with general questions concerning the C language, as defined in the ISO 9899 standard", so _standard C_ here refers to that ISO one.

Comment: You seem to be saying that the [C] tag is incorrect and should not be on the question, since it is not about the C standard.  Mostly though, I was just complaining about the characterization of strptime as "nonstandard" which you've removed.

Comment: @ChrisDodd The C tag's "... as defined in the ISO 9899 standard" is the reference we should work from when considering [C] tagged questions.  "Non-standard C" then refers to things not standardized in the ISO 9899 standard, such as `strptime()` even if defined elsewhere.  As post is also tagged [strptime], Various standards that define it should also be recognized - which is the case with flavors of `*nix` - that was in this answer before the first comment.